# MySQL 8 Update Data From Data in Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-8.0

I am having an issue trying to update a table with data from another table. My statement is below. It seems to fail and the message says it's some SQL Syntax error.

```
UPDATE
    route_info
SET a.address = b.address,
    a.planned_arrival_time = b.planned_arrival_time,
    a.planned_depart_time = b.planned_depart_time,
    a.revised_stop_time = b.revised_stop_time
FROM route_info a, temporary_table b
WHERE a.route_driven_date = b.route_driven_date;
```

The temporary table is where the new data is being store temporarily and has the same format as the existing table `route_info`

I can't figure out why this statement gets rejected.

Error message below:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM temporary_table b AS t\n                WHERE a.route_driven_d' at line 12")
```

Comment: Typo? ... there is an extra comma before FROM.

Comment: oop sorry syntax issue when I typed in the question

Comment: Is there an error message? If so, add it to the question.

Comment: From the error, `FROM temporary_table b AS` is not a part of the posted query? Looks like some other query error.

Comment: Use a JOIN never the `FROM table1,table2`

Comment: Actually, it's this one: `UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references SET ...` .  The `SET` clause follows `table_references`, and `table_references` includes the `JOIN` logic.